# add a new custom field to the register pages

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using Opencart 1.5.5.1.

I have researched for about 2 days now on how to add a new field to my registration pages (create new account, register checkout and guest checkout) but without any luck. It seems nobody has done a step-by-step tutorial on how to do this seeing that (as I understood) it is not that simple.

My question: How can I add new required fields to all my register pages in Opencart 1.5.5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2012/04/recaptcha-captcha-in-open-cart-regiter.html) on how to add re-captcha captcha field in opencart registration page sometime back. Please have a look at this. You can follow this post and achieve what you want with slight modifications.

Comment: I guess there are more turorials on how to add a custom field to some page and that OP could accomodate that tutorial for registration pages, but this one is quite good step-by-step and easy to follow. +1

Comment: @shazin - and also I would like the new field to also appear on the backend on the customer's page but I can't seem to get that to work either